# How to properly return result from a started activity

Tags: android

I have started another activity which I want to return a result to the activity that called it, I have read some tutorial and tried it, but I got some error like this:

```
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=Tab2, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.organizer.medical.activities/.AddPatientActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.organizer.medical.activities/com.organizer.medical.activities.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at com.organizer.medical.activities.PatientActivity.onActivityResult(PatientActivity.java:347)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityGroup.dispatchActivityResult(ActivityGroup.java:122)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
08-23 17:48:58.005: E/AndroidRuntime(581):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my code for the calling activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int cat = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("category").toString());
        loadList(cat);
       }
 }
}
```

This is on my oncreate() on my calling activity:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, CalledActivity.class), ADD_PATIENT);
```

This is my code for the "called" activity:

```
   setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent().putExtra("category", status.isChecked()?1:2));
   finish();
```

By the way on my called activity the `setResult()` and `finish()` is done only `onClick` by a button on that called activity...

I really don't know how to properly use `startActivityForResult()`. Please do share your knowledge about this.

UPDATE

---

Turns out that the intent that i'm accessing on onActivityResult() is causing the null exception error and turns out that the "date" var passed on that method is the one to be used as such:

```
int cat = Integer.parseInt(**data**.getExtras().get("category").toString());
```

Comment: once check your PatientActivity.java line num 347, there you are getting NullPointer exception

Comment: yep its this part:  int cat = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("category").toString()); i don't know wat's wrong where do i got the NullPart.. am i doing wrong in the set result or wat? really have know idea, didn't find any legit explination on the internet..

Comment: have you debugged to this code line? Then you can check which part of the statement is Null.

Comment: @lemoncodes - once try data.getExtras().get("category").toString()

Comment: yep tried debugging, it turned out that @Braj is right, its the intent that cause the null exception error.. tnx guys for the heads up!

Comment: reason behind this I think is, getIntent() is the calling intent and data is the intent sent by other activity which has some data in it

Answer (score 1):

Hello this excample retunrs a string but for an excample it will be fine:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("lastPath", this.myPath.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(b);
setResult(SUCCESS_RETURN_CODE, intent);
finish();
```

To read the values use:

```
Bundle b = data.getExtras();
lastPath = b.getString("lastPath");
```

Comment: already got the answer sir, i used the wrong intent on my code, was very careless :D but anyway tnx for this input im gonna try this too

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the intent that i'm accessing on onActivityResult() is causing the null exception error and turns out that the "date" var passed on that method is the one to be used as such:

int cat = Integer.parseInt(**data**.getExtras().get("category").toString());